# Crashing when I add data to a mutable array from a text box to be displayed in a table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to build a sign-in app but every time I try to add the name and company of a user, the app crashes. I believe it's when I'm trying to take the text from a text field and add it to my mutable array, but I don't know if the error has something to do with the table view or something else along those lines. I already posted a question earlier with a similar error, but now I actually have the table view coming up in the simulator.

Currently both table views are set up to do the same thing. Their dataSources and delegates are connected to File's Owner and they work find when I have test data in the mutable arrays.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

error:

2013-06-03 13:49:03.446 SignIn[12225:11303] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75aa4b0
2013-06-03 13:49:03.447 SignIn[12225:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75aa4b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0x2b96 0x10e3705 0x172c0 0x17258 0xd8021 0xd857f 0xd76e8 0x46cef 0x46f02 0x24d4a 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x13ffc 0x202d 0x1f55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

related code (add method surrounded by **):

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *company;
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *currentNames;
    NSMutableArray *currentCompanies;
    NSMutableArray *names;
    NSMutableArray *companies;
}

@synthesize name, company;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [currentNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [currentNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

**- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    BOOL exists = [names containsObject:name.text];

    if(exists == FALSE){
        [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
        [currentCompanies addObject:[company text]];
        [names addObject:[name text]];
        [companies addObject:[company text]];
    }
    else{
        [currentNames addObject:[name text]];
        [currentCompanies addObject:[company text]];
    }

    name.text=@"";
    company.text=@"";

}**

@end
```

Comment: note that your question is not related to Xcode, please in the future refrain from tagging general iOS programming related questions with the `xcode` tag.

Comment: Sorry. What is the xcode tag meant for then?

Comment: It's reserved for questions about Xcode.

Comment: But not coding in xcode?

Comment: Exactly - this has nothing do do with Xcode since you could be using any other IDE for iOS development, yet your problem would stay exactly the same, regardless of the IDE used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your code, it looks like you never actually created your NSMutableArray objects.

You have them declared, but I don't see any "`alloc`" or "`init`" with them.  So when your current code runs, I'm betting "`companies`", "`names`", etc. are all NULL.

Why not allocate & instantiate your mutable array objects in your "`viewDidLoad`" method?

Comment: It's not crashing! Thank you so much for your help with my past couple of questions :).